# Is it possible to have a simple graph with $4$ vertices, all of which are of different degrees?

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to have a simple graph with $4$ vertices, all of which are of different degrees? If Yes, give an example, and if No, justify why. Generalize your answer in the case where the graph has $n$ vertices.

Answer: No, it not possible because the vertices are even.

Can you tell me whether the answer is correct or not?

Comment: You title is not good but the question itself is acceptable ( and too easy !! )

Answer (score 5):

It is true that there is no such graph, but the reason that you give has nothing to do with the matter. If $G$ is a simple graph with $n$ vertices, the possible degrees of vertices of $G$ are $0,1,\ldots,n-1$: no vertex can be connected by an edge to more than $n-1$ vertices, because there *are* only $n-1$ other vertices, and a simple graph has no multiple (or parallel) edges. If every vertex has a different degree, there would be one vertex of degree $0$, one of degree $1$, and so on up to one of degree $n-1$. I’ll leave the last step to you for now:

- Explain why it is not possible for the graph to have both a vertex of degree $0$ and one of degree $n-1$.

Comment: Always the best answers with complete details !